# How to use Phantom in Scala IDE

Tags: scala, phantom-dsl

I want to use phantom with my scala IDE.So for this i clone the git hub repository and created a .jar file of phantom using sbt -> compile -> package.I add this .jar file to build path in my Scala IDE but still while importing

> `import com.websudos.phantom.connectors._`

is throwing error that

> `object connector is not a member of com.websudos.phantom`.

While using auto complete function of scala ide it is showing only the import for

> `import com.websudos.phantom.example`

.I don't know if the jar files got created for example then why it is not created for other.
I search in internet but all other option are given as to add dependency in sbt build path but i dont want to use it.

Comment: In the error it's `connector` and in the import it is `connectors`, is this a typo in the question or a mistake in some source file?

Comment: Btw, you  can download prebuilt jars here http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/websudos/phantom-dsl_2.11/1.12.2/

Comment: Another observation, it's possible that the package command in Scala IDE is not including transitive dependencies.

Comment: @ivan You should maybe consider using a built tool for a change, this is the wrong approach of dealing with dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Use sbt-assebly instead to create a fat jar.

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly